# EventHandler is null so i cant invoke on MainPage Command using Tapgesturerecognizer

Tags: c#, events, xamarin.ios, event-handling, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am new to deletegate so i dont know how to fix these issue Evenhandler is null and it cannot it main method once clicked here is my code

```
public event EventHandler<CarSchematic.PointEventArgs> TapEvent;
        public void OnTapEvent(float x, float y)
        {
            TapEvent?.Invoke(this, new PointEventArgs(x, y));
        }
```

When TapEvent is return null why it happens how to handled PointEventArgs is class to initiate coordinate x and y axis

Renderer ios code

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Grab the Xamarin.Forms control (not native)
                formsElement = e.NewElement as CustomImage;
                // Grab the native representation of the Xamarin.Forms control
                nativeElement = Control as UIImageView;
                // Set up a tap gesture recognizer on the native control
                nativeElement.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
                UITapGestureRecognizer tgr = new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapHandler);
                nativeElement.AddGestureRecognizer(tgr);
            }
        }

        //
        // Respond to taps.
        //
        public void TapHandler(UITapGestureRecognizer tgr)
        {
            CGPoint touchPoint = tgr.LocationInView(nativeElement);
            formsElement.OnTapEvent(AppState.Xaxis = (float)touchPoint.X, AppState.Yaxis = (float)touchPoint.Y);
        }
```

Xaml code

```
<local:CustomImage  Source="{Binding DamageModel.PhotoSource}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit">
                <local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ImageTapCommand, Source={x:Reference Damage} }" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </local:CustomImage>
```

PageModel

```
public ICommand ImageTapCommand => new FreshCommand(async (obj) =>
                                                           {

                                                               AddDamagePage DamagePage = new AddDamagePage();
                                                               DamagePage.DamageVHCEvent += GoToDamagePage;
                                                               await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(DamagePage);

                                                           });
```

ImageTapCommand cannot trigger when I debug and found TapEvent is null. Thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TapEvent` is null because you not subscribed on it.
According to MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap, you can try to subscribe through:

`Tapped`:

```
<local:CustomImage Source="{Binding DamageModel.PhotoSource}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Aspect="AspectFit">
    <local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="YourTapHandler"  // Here is your tap event handler
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
</local:CustomImage>
```

or `Command`:

```
<local:CustomImage Source="{Binding DamageModel.PhotoSource}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   Aspect="AspectFit">
    <local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
            Command="{Binding YourTapCommand}" // Here is your command handler
            CommandParameter="{Binding ...}" />
    </local:CustomImage.GestureRecognizers>
</local:CustomImage>
```

In your example i didn't see `Command` handler, but you telling that it isn't fired (maybe it not exists?). But there is kind of tap event handler `TapHandler(UITapGestureRecognizer tgr)`, which may be used as `Tapped` handler.

Comment: Still not working for me whenever i tapped IOS TapHandler hitting and CustomImage class Tapevent is null so it could not invoke and not triggered Commands and Tapgesture as well

Comment: Issue is IOS when i tapped the page TapHandler trigger and go to CustomImage class I get X and Y co ordinated but TapEvent is null, so I cant invoke

Comment: You created a custom event from your CustomImage. is there `TapEvent` in xaml to set a handler or command for it?

Comment: Yes thanks Auditive its works fine now

Comment: I have one doubt TapEvent only triggers ImageTapCommand not trigger any suggestion.

Comment: You didn't show us your ImageTapCommand handler, so, probably, it doesn't created by you?

Comment: Edited above ImageTapCommand  added Now working separately Android works imageTapCommand and ios works Tapevent handled any possible both will be handle same